# padding value not accepted

Tags: html, css, reactjs

When I use Material-UI to style card

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  cardGrid: {
    padding: '20px auto'
  },
}))
```

Browser does not accept padding values

Answer (score 1):

auto is not a valid value for padding, you can put 0 instead of 'auto'

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  cardGrid: {
    padding: '20px 0'
  },
}))
```